# Visual Studio Add-In always adds itself to menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I create a visual studio add-in but it adds itself when I open visual studio again and again. Now I have 20 menu in my visual studio :)

How can I check is it already added or not?

I use the following code on Connect.cs [OnStartupComplete method]

I watched this video about adding rigth menu http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb614548.aspx

```
Command command = null;
CommandBarControl commandBarControl;
CommandBar commandBarASPX, commandBarCS;
CommandBars commandBars;

try
{
    try
    {
        command = _applicationObject.Commands.Item(_addInInstance.ProgID + "." + AddInName);
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    if (command == null)
    {
        command = _applicationObject.Commands.AddNamedCommand(_addInInstance, AddInName, AddInButtonName, AddInButtonTooltip, true, 528, null, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled | (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported);
    }
    else
    {
        commandBars = _applicationObject.CommandBars as CommandBars;

        commandBarASPX = commandBars["ASPX Context"];
        commandBarControl = command.AddControl(commandBarASPX, commandBarASPX.Controls.Count + 1) as CommandBarControl;

        commandBarCS = commandBars["Code Window"];
        commandBarControl = command.AddControl(commandBarCS, commandBarCS.Controls.Count + 1) as CommandBarControl;
    }
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exp.Message.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are adding the command at the end of the command list in "ASPX Context" command bar and "Code Window" command bar every time startup completes.

You should rather add the command at a fixed location in the command bar say, at location 1, so that each time it can add the command only if it does not exist.

So you could try the following:

```
commandBarControl = command.AddControl(commandBarASPX, 1) as CommandBarControl;

// ...

commandBarControl = command.AddControl(commandBarCS, 1) as CommandBarControl;
```